# geom_edge_link() in ggraph won't let me specify edge colour

Tags: igraph, ggraph

a bit of a mystery to me here. I'm simply trying to change the edge colour of a graph using ggraph, and the edges go orange no matter what colour I use. for example, here I attempt to set the edge_colour to grey:

```
library(igraph)
library(ggraph)
ring <- sample_k_regular(10, 2)
ggraph(ring) +
geom_edge_link(aes(edge_colour='grey')) +
geom_node_point(shape=21,color='black',size = 7,stroke=1,fill='white'   )+
theme_graph()
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: `aes(edge_color = )` expects an _edge attribute_. If you want just a straight up color, set the `color` argument outside of `aes()`....e.g,. `geom_edge_link(colour='grey')`

Comment: wow thanks. That was simple, thanks.